# Get filepath then append a feature class to that feature class Python Addins

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I'm trying to use tool bar buttons (python addins) to add a filepath and then append another feature class (known to have identical schema, no test needed) to that filepath. My syntax isn't working for some reason.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
import pythonaddins
import re
sdeconn1 = r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\Connection to ffxsde.sde"

class WORKSPACEPATH(object):
    """Implementation for addin_addin.WORKSPACEPATH (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        layer_files = pythonaddins.OpenDialog('Select Layers', True, r'C:\GISData', 'Add')
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()
        list22 = []
        if not isinstance(df, arcpy.mapping.Layer):
            for layer_file in layer_files:
                layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_file)
                list22.append(layer_file)
                pythonaddins.MessageBox(str(list22), 'INFO', 0)
        else:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox('Select a data frame', 'INFO', 0)

class APPEND(object):
    """Implementation for addin_addin.APPEND (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        arcpy.Append_management(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\STW_ST_SIGNS", list22, "NO_TEST","","")
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the Python window of ArcMap to look for any error message thrown when you click the button?

Answer (score 1):

To try and debug this I think you should open the Python window of ArcMap, and look for any error messages thrown when you click the button.

This is described in the [Debugging Python add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p0000001n000000) page of the help:

> When an add-in fails to work, it is commonly due to a coding or syntax
>   error in the Python script. To discover what exception is being
>   raised, open the Python window in ArcGIS. The exception is
>   automatically printed to the Python window, providing the exact
>   location and cause of the error

and it is the first, and usually only, step I need to debug my Python AddIn buttons.